# Kriging of NDVI of Sentinel2

Tags: google-earth-engine

Kriging of NDVI of Sentinel2, I'm getting an error:

```
Want to interpolate pixel values of NDVI obtained from Sentinel2.
Exponential: Tile error: Property ' ndvi ' is missing.
```

My code:

```
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180705T134211_20180705T134414_T21JZN');
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).select('nd').rename('ndvi');

// Define a geometry in which to sample points
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-53.768199, -24.604938, -53.768371, -24.605016]);

// Sample the SSM image at 1000 random locations.
var samples = ndvi.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
  .sample({region: geometry, numPixels: 500})
  .map(function(sample) {
    var lat = sample.get('latitude');
    var lon = sample.get('longitude');
    var sst = sample.get('sst');
    return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]), {sst: sst});
  });

// Interpolate SSM from the sampled points. (gaussian, exponential)
var interpolated = samples.kriging({
  propertyName: 'ndvi',
  shape: 'exponential',
  range: 100 * 1000,
  sill: 1.0,
  nugget: 0.1,
  maxDistance: 100 * 1000,
  reducer: 'mean',
});

var colors = ['00007F', '0000FF', '0074FF',
              '0DFFEA', '8CFF41', 'FFDD00',
              'FF3700', 'C30000', '790000'];
var vis = {min:-3, max:40, palette: colors};

var interpolated = interpolated.clip(Talhao_PR)

Map.setCenter(-53.772523, -24.600772, 16);
Map.addLayer(interpolated, vis, 'Exponential');
Map.addLayer(ndvi, vis, 'NDVI');
Map.addLayer(samples, {}, 'Samples', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you adopt an example code to your purpose, change variables (`ndvi` for `sst`):

```
// Sample the SSM image at 1000 random locations.
var samples = ndvi.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
  .sample({region: geometry, numPixels: 500})
  .map(function(sample) {
    var lat = sample.get('latitude');
    var lon = sample.get('longitude');
    var ndvi = sample.get('ndvi');
    return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]), {ndvi: ndvi});
  });
```

BTW, check sample points output